# Consulta GET en View Laravel

Tags: eloquent

Estoy haciendo una consulta a BBDD desde una vista con eloquent para imprimir una tabla, el caso es que funciona pero antes de la tabla, donde tengo la consulta me imprime el array.

¿Como debo hacer la consulta para que únicamente guarde los datos para utilizarlos en la tabla pero que no me lo imprima en la página?

```
{{ $zero_users = DB::table('empleados')->where('estado', 0)->get() }}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, la consulta a tu DB la deberías hacer en tu modelo y en el `render()` pasar la variable con los resultados, desde tu vista utilizas la variable que pasas desde el `render` para llenar los datos de tu tabla

Comment: OK, pensé que era más sencillo haciendo la consulta directamente desde la vista, todavía voy aprendiendo. Hasta ahora en los modelos devuelvo directamente una vista pero en este caso no sé como llamar desde la vista a una función del modelo.

Comment: Agrega tu modelo para poder ayudarte a hacer la consulta ahí y pasar la información a través del `render()`

Comment: Gracias, añadido a la pregunta, estoy algo perdido...

Comment: Perdona, lo que quería ver es tu controlador, me confundí jaja, mientras voy redactando la respuesta

Comment: No me deja añadir el controlador por exceso de código...

Comment: solo has el update y agregas el `return Redirect::back();` en lugar de una vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

En tu controlador hay un método `show` que sirve para devolver la vista que vas a mostrar, puedes pasar la respuesta de la consulta que haces a tu base de datos de la siguiente forma (A continuación muestro un ejemplo que debes adaptar a tu controlador, desconozco el nombre de tu vista así que puse user.profile):

```
public function show($id)
{
    return view('user.profile', [
        'zero_users' => DB::table('empleados')->where('estado', 0)->get()
    ]);
}
```

Aunque yo te recomendaría crear primero una variable con tu consulta (Así puedes hacer `dd()` para ver si te devuelve la información correcta

```
public function show($id)
{
    $zero_users = DB::table('empleados')->where('estado', 0)->get()
    // Si necesitas comprobar $zero_users puedes hacer dd($zero_users)

    return view('user.profile', [
        'zero_users' => $zero_users
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco de veras pero creo que no me he explicado bien, esto ya lo tengo hecho con un CRUD a cada una de las vistas, defino la ruta y desde el controlador apunto a la vista. El tema es que en el dashboard de adminlte quiero añadir dos tablas con solo una parte de los datos y claro, a esta vista dashboard no llego desde el controlador :/

Comment: Me falta bastante aún por aprender, en ello estoy...

Comment: Pero ¿Ya tienes la consulta hecha en el controlador? Si necesitas datos de otro modelo también los puedes pasar en el mismo controlador

Comment: No, esta consulta concreta no pero es que este controlador no me lleva a la vista Dashboard, no tengo la ruta apuntando aquí, supongo que es más problema mío de que aún acabo de comprender conceptualmente el esquema con Laravel, no te preocupes, sigo estudiando e investigando.

Comment: Ok, pero, ¿Tu problema está resuelto?

Comment: No, pero no me va de un par de días de seguir leyendo y tratando de entender exactamente el MVC en Laravel, si me das el código seguiré sin entenderlo, te lo agradezco de veras pero voy a tratar de centrarme en comprender lo que debo hacer antes de hacerlo ;)